# How to prevent a whole list from re-rendering when editing an element on the list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created this very simple app to hopefully explain this problem.

I tried using memoization and callback, but I believe it's re-rendering because the playerArr is always changing once I type into the text input.

my actual lists are only 15 elements in size, but the re-render is causing it to become REALLY SLOW when typing into the input.

Any suggestions?  I have a deadline and i'm getting stressed out =(  will going back to non-hooks help?  or implementing redux?  not sure the performance factor.

```
function App() {
  const [player1, setPlayer1] = React.useState({
    firstName: "First",
    lastName: "Last ",
    id: uuidv4()
  });

  const [player2, setPlayer2] = React.useState({
    firstName: "First",
    lastName: "Last",
    id: uuidv4()
  });

  const [player3, setPlayer3] = React.useState({
    firstName: "First",
    lastName: "Last",
    id: uuidv4()
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <State
        player1={player1}
        player2={player2}
        player3={player3}
        setPlayer1={setPlayer1}
        setPlayer2={setPlayer2}
        setPlayer3={setPlayer3}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

//----------------------------------------------------------

export const State = React.memo(({player1, player2, player3, setPlayer1, setPlayer2, setPlayer3}) => {
  const playerArr = [player1, player2, player3];
  const setPlayerArr = [setPlayer1, setPlayer2, setPlayer3];

  return (
    <div>
      <Playlist
        playerArr={playerArr}
        setPlayerArr={setPlayerArr}
      />
    </div>
  );
});

//----------------------------------------------------------

export const Playlist = React.memo(({playerArr, setPlayerArr}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        playerArr.map((player, index) => (
          <Player
            key={player.id}
            player={player}
            setPlayer={setPlayerArr[index]}
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
});

//----------------------------------------------------------

export const Player = React.memo(({player, setPlayer}) => {
  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const playerCopy = {...player};
    playerCopy[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setPlayer(playerCopy);
  }, [player, setPlayer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type={"text"} name={"firstName"} value={player.firstName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      <input type={"text"} name={"lastName"} value={player.lastName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
    </div>
  );
});
```

EDIT: i edited app per discussion.  same thing happening

Comment: That would be because you define the player array where the rendering happens.

Comment: @JohnRuddell hey again!  what would be the best way to go around this then?  thank you for the help last night

Comment: Oh hey haha! I would probably make this a class component lol

Comment: @JohnRuddell LOL.  would making this a class component really prevent the re-rendering though?  Why would this be different in comparison to hooks?  I'd still be essentially doing the same thing wouldn't i?

Comment: Well no, because this function is essentially `render` in a component class. You could move the player array initialization to outside `App` and see if that fixes it

Comment: @JohnRuddell okay i will try right now

Comment: @JohnRuddell I rewrote a part an added a State layer.  maybe i misunderstood but was this what you meant?  I can't put it outside of App as that's the app load point, but I tried to recreate what you meant?  It doesn't work though.

Comment: do you have a link or something i can look at?

Comment: @JohnRuddell https://github.com/DaleSalcedo/TestingListRendering

Comment: I would probably do something like this. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-63f0t . If you look at the console logs you see the items that are rendering. You shouldn't really worry about anything heavier in terms of performance unless you really need to.

Comment: @JohnRuddell thanks John for taking the time.  will check it out right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you do, your `<App>` and `<Playlist>` components (even if they are memoized) will HAVE to re-render every time there is a user input because that is where you are storing your state, and is to be expected.

The best you can do is memoize each `<Player>` component so that when the list re-renders, every individual list item doesn't necessarily re-render itself. To do this you can pass an "areEqual" function as the second argument to `React.memo`. See the example in the React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

In your case, it would probably look something like this:

```
export const Player = React.memo(({player, setPlayer}) => {
  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const playerCopy = {...player};
    playerCopy[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setPlayer(playerCopy);
  }, [player, setPlayer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type={"text"} name={"firstName"} value={player.firstName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      <input type={"text"} name={"lastName"} value={player.lastName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  // Check to see if the data is the same
  if (prevProps.firstName === nextProps.firstName
    && prevProps.lastName === nextProps.lastName
    && prevProps.id === nextProps.id) {
    return true; // Return true if they ARE the same
  } else {
    return false; // Return false if they are NOT the same
  }
});
```

Sometimes, if the data you are comparing is a simple collection of strings and/or numbers, you can use `JSON.stringify` as a shorthand way to convert it to a string and compare the strings:

```
export const Player = React.memo(({player, setPlayer}) => {
  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    const playerCopy = {...player};
    playerCopy[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setPlayer(playerCopy);
  }, [player, setPlayer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type={"text"} name={"firstName"} value={player.firstName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      <input type={"text"} name={"lastName"} value={player.lastName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  // Check to see if the data is the same
  if (JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps)) {
    return true; // Return true if they ARE the same
  } else {
    return false; // Return false if they are NOT the same
  }
});
```

Comment: hey jered, your theory definitely makes sense.  i figured there was no real way around it but i like your memoization example and theory.  though I did try to apply it to my current code https://github.com/DaleSalcedo/TestingListRendering but it's not letting me type into the textbox anymore.  I'm not sure why

Comment: actually i put a breakpoint into the return true and return false of the comparing props and it seems everytime i type it hits the return true all 3 times instead of 1 of them going to false.

Comment: ok nevermind it seems i need to do prevProps.player.firstName not prevProps.firstName.  let me fix and will let u know

Comment: okay i got it to work.  using the React plugin --> options --> highlight updates it doesn't seem any different unfortunately.  But what you said logically makes the most sense and i'm pretty sure this is the best it's going to get.  will leave this up for discussion a bit more just to see what others think and suggest.  thank you jered.  i'm going to apply this to my actual work application and see if this helps and will let you know

Comment: hey jered I'm trying to use your example on something just barely slightly more complicated but I can't get it to work as it returns the text input to an older value?  it's weird.. but i made a demo here.. no one's answering was hoping you could take a look.. i'm desperate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56944519/using-prevprops-and-nextprops-in-a-react-memo-component-to-prevent-unnecessary-r