# Comparing prevProps and nextProps in a React.memo Component to prevent unnecessary re-rendering but it's acting funny

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-germain-mgd64

If you type something in one person's name, then switch to another person and type around, you will see it will change the other person's name back to the original.  But it doesn't make sense why it's doing that.  If I remove the whole prevProps and nextProps comparison it works fine.

Though this works in a much more simpler example just fine. I'm not sure why it's not working in this scenario though.

More detail on what I'm trying to do as far as comparing props found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Player Component using the Memo is here:

```
export const Player = React.memo(({player, modifyPlayer}) => {
  const handleOnChange = React.useCallback((event) => {
    modifyPlayer(player.id, event.target.name, event.target.value);
  }, [player, modifyPlayer]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type={"text"} name={"firstName"} value={player.firstName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
      <input type={"text"} name={"lastName"} value={player.lastName} onChange={handleOnChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}, 
(prevProps, nextProps) => {
  // Check to see if the data is the same
  if (prevProps.player.firstName === nextProps.player.firstName
    && prevProps.player.lastName === nextProps.player.lastName
    && prevProps.player.id === nextProps.player.id) {
    return true; // Return true if they ARE the same
  } else {
    return false; // Return false if they are NOT the same
    // EVEN THOUGH THIS RETURNS FALSE IT MESSES UP THE OTHER TEXT
  }
});
```

App Component

```
function App() {
  const [playerDict, setPlayerDict] = React.useState(
    {
      id1: {
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        id: 'id1'
      },
      id2: {
        firstName: "Michael",
        lastName: "Creaton",
        id: 'id2'
      },
      id3: {
        firstName: "William",
        lastName: "Shakespeare",
        id: 'id3'
      },
    }

  );
  const [playerIdList, setPlayerIdList] = React.useState(['id1', 'id2', 'id3']);

  const modifyPlayer = React.useCallback((playerId, propertyName, value) => {
    const playerCopy = {...playerDict[playerId]};
    playerCopy[propertyName] = value;
    const playerDictCopy = {
      ...playerDict,
      [playerId]: playerCopy
    };
    setPlayerDict(playerDictCopy);
  }
  ,[playerDict]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Playlist
        modifyPlayer={modifyPlayer}
        playlist={playerIdList.map(playerId => playerDict[playerId])}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Playlist Component

```
export const Playlist = React.memo(({modifyPlayer, playlist}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        playlist.map((player) => (
          <Player
            key={player.id}
            player={player}
            modifyPlayer={modifyPlayer}
          />
        ))
      }
    </div>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a good head-scratcher, but I think I found the issue.

When you create your callback `modifyPlayer` you rightly pass `playerDict` as a dependency, since the callback relies on having an "up to date" version of `playerDict` *before* it can create a new version of `playerDict` using the latest update event. But this also means that each time the the depencendy `playerDict` changes (with every change event) you will get a new `modifyPlayer`-callback function.

But the `areEqual` function in the `Player`-component (around line 29) says that the component should only update if any of the `player` properties have changed (id, firstName or lastName), this means that the component never receives the updated callback-function, so it will try to update the the `playerDict` using the "wrong" previous version of the data (because it has a previous version of the callback function).

Including a check for equality between `prevProps.modifyPlayer` and `nextProps.modifyPlayer` makes the code behave like expected again:

```
// in Player.js - around line 29
(prevProps, nextProps) => {
    // Check to see if the data is the same
    if (
      prevProps.player.firstName === nextProps.player.firstName &&
      prevProps.player.lastName === nextProps.player.lastName &&
      prevProps.player.id === nextProps.player.id && 
      prevProps.modifyPlayer === nextProps.modifyPlayer
    ) {
      return true; // Return true if they ARE the same
    } else {
      return false; // Return false if they are NOT the same
    }
  }
```

**Edit:** Updated demo code here https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-surf-nu6tt

Comment: will be at work in a few hours thank you so much for this!  will let you know!

Comment: oh goodness that was it?  i really like that you explained WHY which really helps me with understanding...  thank you so much you're the man

Comment: Hehe, yeah that's a tiny change making a pretty big difference. Thank you for your kind feedback, I'm glad I could help!